# Android Studio - Expression Expected

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating a weather app and I am getting a message that an Expression was expected.

Here is my Main Activity:

```
package com.haziqhussain.hazweather;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class WeatherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_weather);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new WeatherFragment())
                .commit();
    }



}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    /*int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);*/
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.change_city){
        showInputDialog();
    }
    return false;

}


private void showInputDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Change city");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            changeCity(input.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

public void changeCity(String city){
    WeatherFragment wf = (----->WeatherFragment<------).getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    wf.changeCity(city);
    new CityPreference(this).setCity(city);
}

}
```

The Error is in the Public Void ChangeCity where weather fragment is being called. This is an error that keeps occuring and I am not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
public void changeCity(String city){
WeatherFragment wf = (WeatherFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.container); // removed '.' 
wf.changeCity(city);
(new CityPreference(this)).setCity(city);
```

}

Comment: Thanks, this really helped!